# ASP.NET Core Data Encryption/Protection

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption, entity-framework-core, mariadb, data-protection

I have a shared Database for a Multi-Tenant WebApplication, that uses Entity Framework Core. The Tenants have their own Tenant Table and every model has a Tenant ID.
By Design it is not possible to access the data of another Tenant because I have Query Filters and the code in the controllers always checks TenantId.
But I would like to encrypt the data of each Tenant or at least the most sensetive data with a different key or purpose string.
I implemented it for one model with the Protection API.

It would be a lot of work though to implement it for every model, because I have to call protect and unprotect after every Database call in the controller.

I am using MariaDB as my Database. Does somebody know if it is possible to let MariaDB do the encrypting? I know you can encrypt the data at rest, but is it also possible to encrypt different rows identified by TenantId with a different key?

Comment: DB-side encryption is good only against someone that can read the DB files directly, but won't protect against a faulty client that mixed up tenants.

Comment: Possibly what you've done is among the best way. For a more massive application I would put that encryption/decryption in the repositories, so the controllers don't even know about it and it's centraliced in a single place.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro I implemented it in my repositories. Now it is not in the controllers which makes them more readable thanks for your good advice.